# Асинхронное вычисление NODE.JS

Tags: node.js, асинхронность

Здравствуйте, предположим, что у меня есть некоторая последовательность, **например** 1,2,3,4..
Мне нужно найти ее сумму, я накидал следующий прототип.

```
function test(start, offset) {
  sum = 0;
  for (i=start;i<start+offset;++i)
    sum+=i;
  return sum;
}
```

вопрос, как запустить вычисление в несколько потоков (асинхронно) без SetTimeout тем самым найдя сумму частей ряда и потом, отловить завершение вычисления кусков, сложить все в одну сумму и вывести. В ноде новичок, помогите советом.

Comment: а Вы уверенны, что нода именно для этого предназначена? Она умеет эффективно распараллелить к примеру http запросы, но суммирование ряда... Разве что у Вас есть сторонний сервис, который умеет это делать.

Comment: Мне не нужно, чтобы вы отговаривали - это лишь абстрактный пример. Я хочу понять, как запустить множество функций на выполнение одновременно и после собрать результат.

Comment: функции должны делать долгую работу? например, что то считать? (не путать с запросом к базе - там две части - запрос и получение результата. Оно хоть и долго, но по средине пауза).

Comment: да, функции исключительно делают долгую работу без всяких пауз, мне просто нужно понять как запустить одновременно и собрать результаты их работы.

Comment: никак. Нода однопоточная.

Comment: В определении ноды сказано, что она асинхронна. А это значит, что я могу запустить следующую функцию пока не окончена предыдущая, что я и хочу сделать. Я уверен, что вы ошибаетесь. Погуглил на библиотеку DO, которая вроде как может подождать, но не очень понял как работает да и мне не нужно столько наворотов.

Comment: Если для суммирования напишете свою программу (отдельно), то тогда эта библиотека do может помочь.  А если средствами только одной ноды - никак. Асинхронное не значит многопоточное. Нода не может одновременно выполнять несколько функций. Только по очереди.

Comment: Подскажите как реализовать это асинхронно.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/138629/ тут поищите слово "web workers"

Comment: нода асинхронна по IO и прочим внешним вызовам. если обращений вовне не будет, то javascript будет выполняться строго синхронно, т.е. последовательно.  

ЗЫ вы уверены, что читаете что сами пишите? в вопросе у вас написано про несколько потоков, что это как не многопоточность?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov в ноде реализованы форки и треды, т.е. мы можем с текущим состоянием переменных сделать отдельный воркер, но естественно его переменные не будут самостоятельно менять переменные в основном процессе и переменные в основном процессе, после запуска воркера не будут влиять на переменные в воркере, тем не менее форкнуть можно и можно передать воркеру callbacks. (т.е. можно получать события из воркера)

Comment: @eicto именно. воркеры - это отдельные процессы, на один процесс может быть только один тред. в рамках одного процесса распараллелить вычисления нет возможности. а вариантов как сделать параллельные вычисления вне мастер-процесса великое множество. Как раз то, о чем говорит @KoVadim. Там и аддоны, и отдельные сервера, и воркеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, из коробки, нельзя, но, если действительно нужно, можно воспользоватся нативным модулем который предоставляет необходимый вам функционал, например я, однажды, использовал [node-webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads). Рекомендую всегда замерять производительность перед использованием, с довольно большим шансом, использование тредов не улучшит скорость работы, возможно даже ухудшит, либо улучшит незначительно, но, при этом, значительно возрастет нагрузка CPU. Это с т.з. прямого ответа на заданный вами вопрос.

Но, предположу, что вас интересует - как быть с ситуацией, когда у вас есть очередь клиентов (например http сервера) и каждому из них "нужно" сделать, потенциально, какие-то довольно длительные вычисления(допустим цикл по массиву неизвестной длины). Если это так, то, в таком случае, напишите "асинхронный" цикл обработки так, что-бы каждая следующая итерация "цикла" вызывалась использую process.nextTick (e.g. setTimeout(fn, 0)). Конечно-же, это не даст вам прироста с т.з. скорости вычисления, скорее, даже, хоть и незначительно, но - уменьшит, но, зато, все клиенты получат ответ с минимальной разницей во времени, чего не происходит в случае цикла "в лоб" т.к. в таком случае 2ой клиент ждет пока отработает весь цикл первого, потом третий ждет 2ого, в общем все довольно таки плохо.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js имеет асинхронную однопоточную модель.
Можно погуглить про загрузку нескольких копий приложения и распределения задач между ними или про WebWorker'ы из стандарта HTML5. Но это все магия... Нужно строить архитектуру так, чтобы это не требовалось или эту работу выполняли другие.